# SVG - Angular Gradient Issue inside HTML

Tags: html, css, svg

I created a loading Icon in **FIGMA** and after copying it from that I pasted it in `HTML` but it is not rendering entirely, half of it is not displaying. I don't if it is hidden or not.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

svg {
  width    : 200px;
  height   : 200px;
  overflow : visible;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 28 28" fill="none">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15 7C15 7.55228 14.5523 8 14 8C13.4477 8 13 7.55228 13 7V1C13 0.447715 13.4477 0 14 0C14.5523 0 15 0.447715 15 1V7ZM11 8.80384C11.4783 8.5277 11.6421 7.91611 11.366 7.43782L8.36601 2.24167C8.08987 1.76337 7.47827 1.5995 6.99998 1.87564C6.52169 2.15178 6.35781 2.76337 6.63396 3.24167L9.63396 8.43782C9.9101 8.91611 10.5217 9.07999 11 8.80384ZM8.43786 9.63399C8.91615 9.91013 9.08003 10.5217 8.80388 11C8.52774 11.4783 7.91615 11.6422 7.43786 11.366L2.24171 8.36604C1.76341 8.0899 1.59954 7.47831 1.87568 7.00001C2.15182 6.52172 2.76341 6.35784 3.24171 6.63399L8.43786 9.63399ZM8 14C8 13.4477 7.55228 13 7 13H1C0.447715 13 0 13.4477 0 14C0 14.5523 0.447715 15 1 15H7C7.55228 15 8 14.5523 8 14ZM7.43789 16.6339C7.91618 16.3578 8.52777 16.5217 8.80391 17C9.08006 17.4783 8.91618 18.0899 8.43789 18.366L3.24174 21.366C2.76344 21.6421 2.15185 21.4783 1.87571 21C1.59957 20.5217 1.76344 19.9101 2.24174 19.6339L7.43789 16.6339ZM11 19.1962C10.5217 18.92 9.91009 19.0839 9.63395 19.5622L6.63395 24.7584C6.35781 25.2366 6.52169 25.8482 6.99998 26.1244C7.47827 26.4005 8.08986 26.2366 8.366 25.7584L11.366 20.5622C11.6421 20.0839 11.4783 19.4723 11 19.1962ZM14.0001 20C13.4478 20 13.0001 20.4477 13.0001 21V27C13.0001 27.5523 13.4478 28 14.0001 28C14.5523 28 15.0001 27.5523 15.0001 27V21C15.0001 20.4477 14.5523 20 14.0001 20ZM17.0001 8.80381C17.4784 9.07996 18.09 8.91608 18.3661 8.43779L21.3661 3.24164C21.6423 2.76334 21.4784 2.15175 21.0001 1.87561C20.5218 1.59947 19.9102 1.76334 19.6341 2.24164L16.6341 7.43779C16.3579 7.91608 16.5218 8.52767 17.0001 8.80381ZM20.5622 11.366C20.0839 11.6422 19.4723 11.4783 19.1961 11C18.92 10.5217 19.0839 9.91013 19.5622 9.63399L24.7583 6.63399C25.2366 6.35785 25.8482 6.52173 26.1243 7.00002C26.4005 7.47831 26.2366 8.0899 25.7583 8.36604L20.5622 11.366ZM20.0001 14C20.0001 14.5523 20.4478 15 21.0001 15H27.0001C27.5523 15 28.0001 14.5523 28.0001 14C28.0001 13.4477 27.5523 13 27.0001 13H21.0001C20.4478 13 20.0001 13.4477 20.0001 14ZM19.5622 18.366C19.0839 18.0899 18.92 17.4783 19.1962 17C19.4723 16.5217 20.0839 16.3578 20.5622 16.634L25.7584 19.634C26.2366 19.9101 26.4005 20.5217 26.1244 21C25.8482 21.4783 25.2366 21.6421 24.7584 21.366L19.5622 18.366ZM17.0001 19.1961C16.5218 19.4723 16.3579 20.0839 16.6341 20.5622L19.6341 25.7583C19.9102 26.2366 20.5218 26.4005 21.0001 26.1244C21.4784 25.8482 21.6422 25.2366 21.3661 24.7583L18.3661 19.5622C18.09 19.0839 17.4784 18.92 17.0001 19.1961Z" fill="url(#gradient)" />

    <defs>
        <radialGradient id="gradient" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(14 14) scale(14)">
            <stop offset="0.669733" stop-color="#595F67" />
            <stop offset="0.716307" stop-color="#262626" stop-opacity="0.01" />
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I even set `svg { overflow: visible; }` but nothing worked!

**NOTE**

As `ÁlvaroGonzález` complaint of its small size I increased it.

**IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS**
[image]

**FIGMA FILE** Try this [Loader](https://www.figma.com/file/fED9r4ShDnIZt9rREvixBH/Spinner?node-id=0%3A1)

Comment: @MisterJojo what do you mean by that??

Comment: For me, it shows up in the Stack Overflow snippet, although it looks quite small: https://i.imgur.com/1ygJSwz.png

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález well you can increase its ```width``` and ```height```. But it will still not display entire **SVG**

Comment: @KunalTanwar your entire SVG is displayed, but the gradient hides all over 0.71% from the center. That's isn't the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/dwz31Lpx/. The problem is how to make each stick of the loader transparent by decreasing the opacity.

Comment: @Leonid then why it is looking completely fine in **FIGMA**??

Comment: @Leonid I added Figma File Link!

Comment: I posted the code above! BRO....

Comment: @KunalTanwar I got it, but I look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/radialGradient and don't see in what case the result image has a chance to look like you want. There is no way I guess...

Comment: The only way as for me is to put a path of a stick in `<def>` or `<symbol>` and put each of 12 by `<use>` with rotate transformation and changing the opacity of each. Using JS should be more convenient as I see it.

Comment: As a reply to your prior comment - I am not using radial-gradient. Instead I used angular-gradient. You are right even though I used angular gradient in **FIGMA** it is getting converted in radial-gradient automatically. [Take a Look](https://spectrum.chat/figma/help/svg-export-angular-gradient-issue~4ebab431-f6f3-4dfb-bec6-d02f077f2a38)

Comment: @KunalTanwar I can clearly see the `<radialGradient id="gradient">` in your code. Also I didn't find any angularGradient docs... Would you please give me a link for that?

Comment: Anyway there is nothing mysterious in partial disappearing of the loader - that is the way how the radialGradient works.

Comment: Btw Thank You So Much @Leonid 

Comment: Have you solved?

Comment: As others have said, this is obviously a bug in Figma's SVG exporter. Those sort of gradients are not supported in SVGs. You might like to report this bug to them. As a solution, change your Figma file so that it doesn't use a gradient. Change the olour of each of the twelve parts to a solid colour that has the right shade of grey. Then re-export your SVG.

Comment: @Hoch Nope! I didn't

Comment: @KunalTanwar i can't see the figma file, can you share again?

Comment: I'm going to write what I think it is: The radial gradient goes from the center to the edges, right? You have an svg with a gradient that goes from #595F67 to #262626 with 0.01 opacity, meaning the edges will be almost transparent, right? Now, to get the same effect, the designer would have to make each line of the loader with a different vector, unfortunately we don't have gradient lineader for this type of object (A straight line but in the end follows a circular path).

Comment: @Hoch it is a lot more complicated than I assumed 

Comment: Talk with your designer to change for one these: https://loading.io/css/ - the last one is close to your print.

Comment: The spinner consist of 9 Childs and 1 parent div I don't want that many code for a simple spinner. Btw Thanks for your guidance although I updated the figma link see if you can do anything 